# Using a crossfader in a passive circuit

Tags: mixer, diy, engineering

I'm trying to build a really simple passive summing circuit for combining two line-level stereo audio sources (iPod + laptop or iPod + iPod), and I really want to be able to fade between the sources.

Basically, this would be between the audio source and the "tape input" on a PA.

I'm considering a [dual gang slide potentiometer](http://www.mouser.com/Search/ProductDetail.aspx?qs=U%2FacTlguYxawWcnlXpg7xA%3D%3D) -- would that be enough, as long as I converted the stereo signals to mono first?

What about using a [replacement crossfader from a DJ mixer](http://www.planetdj.com/i--RS-50T)?  I imagine a lot of them are proprietary to a specific mixer, but are there any that I could just drop into a passive circuit?